# Count child tables in table cell

Tags: vba, ms-word

In a `Wordtable` with several rows, i need to count how many sub-tables there are in each row. Each row has two columns and the sub-tables are placed in the second column, i.e. `Cell(row, 2)`.

Something like:

```
For Each oRow In tblTable.Rows
    iCountTables = tblTable.Cell(oRow, 2).Tables.Count
Next
```

but that actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub TableChildCounter()

    Dim CurrentDoc As Document
    Dim CurrentTbl As Table
    Dim CurrentRow As Row
    Dim TablesInCol2 As Long

    Set CurrentDoc = ActiveDocument



    For Each CurrentTbl In CurrentDoc.Tables

        For Each CurrentRow In CurrentTbl.Rows

            TablesInCol2 = CurrentRow.Cells(2).Tables.Count
            MsgBox TablesInCol2

        Next CurrentRow

    Next CurrentTbl

End Sub
```

Comment: @RogZen good stuff. Remember to upvote the answers you find helpful on all posts as well at the answer you choose to be correct. Enjoy stackoverflow.